# Strange recurring errors downloading python 3.10.9.tgz with wget

Tags: python, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wget

I and several workmates have had a recurring problem building python in a docker container under WSL and VirtualBox. The download seems to succeed but then the unzipping reports 'trailing garbage ignored', and the build process exits with value 2. We typically hit this problem a few times, do a manual workaround and then don't see it for a while, so it feels intermittent.

If downloaded via a browser, or even directly from the command line (with wget) the process works, but if you get the file with by running a script that calls `wget`, it most often has this 'trailing garbage ignored' error, even though the downloaded file reports the same total number of bytes exactly.

I'm trying to eliminate this so our dev setup can be hassle free but I'm at a loss as to what is going wrong.

My most recent experience with this was this morning:
Running the wget command inside a bash script produced a file that unzipped with errors, pasting the same lines to a terminal downloaded the file and it unzipped perfectly.

```
> `# environment values
> 
>   PYTHON_DOCKER_IMAGE="ken/python"   
>   PYTHON_DOCKER_TAG="3.10.9"  
>   UBI_DOCKER_IMAGE="redhat/ubi8"   
>   UBI_DOCKER_TAG="8.7" `

# build_local.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

function build_local() {
  mkdir -p output
  wget \
    -c \
    --no-cache \
    -O output/python.tar.gz \
    "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_DOCKER_TAG}/Python-${PYTHON_DOCKER_TAG}.tgz"

  docker build \
    --file Dockerfile.python \
    --build-arg UBI_DOCKER_IMAGE="${UBI_DOCKER_IMAGE}" \
    --build-arg UBI_DOCKER_TAG="${UBI_DOCKER_TAG}" \
    --tag "${PYTHON_DOCKER_IMAGE}:${PYTHON_DOCKER_TAG}" \
    --tag "${PYTHON_DOCKER_IMAGE}:latest" \
    .

  docker compose -p "${PROJECT_NAME}" build
}

function main() {
  build_local "$@"
}

main "$@"`
```

This is the Dockerfile that builds Python. We don't use the pre-built images due to access issues on the work network.

```
`# Dockerfile.python

[snipped basic construction from redhat ubi]

COPY output/python.tar.gz /

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/src/python && \
    tar -zxf python.tar.gz -C /usr/local/src/python --strip-components=1 && \
    cd /usr/local/src/python && \
    ./configure \
      --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions \
      --enable-optimizations \
      --enable-option-checking=fatal \
      --with-system-expat \
      --with-ensurepip && \
    make && \
    make altinstall

[snipped a bunch of subsequent construction that runs if the previous lines run, and isn't reached if they fail.]
```

Comment: It's not reproducible? I thought you and several colleagues were experiencing it consistently? In any case, if it's not reproducible there's nothing we can do.

Comment: the backslash is a line continuation so that it works in the script.  I will put the scripts in.

Comment: separated arguments are nice (with line continuations), but to eliminate a possible problem try running it will all arguments on the same line (I have seen this cause problems, honest (-;! ) . Good luck.

Comment: I'm going to guess that somehow you have a race condition somewhere. You likely end up with multiple instances of Wget trying to write to the same file leading to garbage data. Try changing your wget command line to write the file to a unique location for every process and see if you can reproduce the issue